# FirebaseMessagingService shows dialog box when app is in foreground android and receives push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, dialog, foreground

I am getting below `dialog` box when my app is in foreground and I receive an `push notification`. I am pretty sure I am not doing any specific code to show such `dialog` box.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
    {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    }
}
```

My question is how can I `override` this dialog box or how can I replace it with my own dialog box?

I am beginner in the push notification world so any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: post more codes if possible

Comment: Server handles the notification part. I am just receiving it. So I am not sure what other code you might be needing. Please let me know so I can post it. @Darush

Comment: remove super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage) and see if it helps.

Comment: Nope. I can still see the dialog box. @Darush

Comment: where is this onMessageReceived declared? are you extending the FirebaseMessagingService class?

Comment: Yes. Please see the updated code. @Darush

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157940/discussion-between-darush-and-pooja).